# React convert timestamp to date time inside ".map" function

Tags: reactjs

I am building a table that fetches data from a json API. The API gives measurments on electricity power flow between diffrent countries, example:

**GetFlow.json**

```
[
  {
    "OutAreaElspotId": "DE",
    "InAreaElspotId": "SE4",
    "Value": -615,
    "MeasureDate": 1646123700000
  },
  {
    "OutAreaElspotId": "DK1",
    "InAreaElspotId": "DE",
    "Value": 1211.7925,
    "MeasureDate": 1646123700000
  },
  {
    "OutAreaElspotId": "DK1",
    "InAreaElspotId": "NL",
    "Value": 699.8785,
    "MeasureDate": 1646123700000
  }
]
```

I have managed to display the data in a HTML table:

[image]

My problem is that the Measure Date field is in seconds and not a real date and time. It is impossible for the usewr of the table to know what it means..

My code is as following:

**PhysicalFlow.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PhysicalFlow extends React.Component {
  state = {
    flows: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    let config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      }
    }
    
    let data = {
      'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': 'no',
    }

    axios.get('http://localhost:8010/proxy/restapi/PhysicalFlowMap/GetFlow', data, config)
      .then(res => {
        const flows = res.data;
        this.setState({ flows });
      })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="hor-zebra">
       <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span>Area</span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span>To</span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span>Measure Date</span>
          </th>
          <th>
            <span>Value</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
        {
          this.state.flows
            .map(flow =>
       
              <tr key={flow.InAreaElspotId}>
               <td><span>{flow.InAreaElspotId}</span></td>
               <td><span>{flow.OutAreaElspotId}</span></td>
               <td><span>{flow.MeasureDate}</span></td>
               <td><span>{flow.Value}</span></td>
             </tr>
            )
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  };
};
```

Now I have found the following code for converting data:

```
var t = new Date();
t.setSeconds( 1370001284 );
var formatted = moment(t).format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

But I am unsure where I can place that code. I tried to put it into the .map function like this but it failed:

```
{
  this.state.flows
    .map(flow =>

      var t = new Date();
      t.setSeconds( flow.MeasureDate );
      var measureDateSaying = moment(t).format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");

      <tr key={flow.InAreaElspotId}>
       <td><span>{flow.InAreaElspotId}</span></td>
       <td><span>{flow.OutAreaElspotId}</span></td>
       <td><span>{measureDateSaying}</span></td>
       <td><span>{flow.Value}</span></td>
     </tr>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. You just missed the brackets and the return statement.

```jsx
this.state.flows
    .map(flow => {
      var t = new Date();
      t.setSeconds( flow.MeasureDate );
      var measureDateSaying = moment(t).format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");

      return ( 
        <tr key={flow.InAreaElspotId}>
          <td><span>{flow.InAreaElspotId}</span></td>
          <td><span>{flow.OutAreaElspotId}</span></td>
          <td><span>{measureDateSaying}</span></td>
          <td><span>{flow.Value}</span></td>
        </tr>
      );
     }
    )
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you forgot to add a block inside map, so you can do more stuff in it:

```
this.state.flows.map((flow) => {
   var t = new Date();
   t.setSeconds( flow.MeasureDate );
   var measureDateSaying = moment(t).format("dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss");

   return (
     <tr key={flow.InAreaElspotId}>
      <td><span>{flow.InAreaElspotId}</span></td>
      <td><span>{flow.OutAreaElspotId}</span></td>
      <td><span>{measureDateSaying}</span></td>
      <td><span>{flow.Value}</span></td>
    </tr>
   )
 }
```